# Create/Update tags in Azure using API

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How do we create a new tag or update an already existing tag on a azure resource(VM, DB, function app).
AWS has create_tags for instances, image ..Is there any such way in azure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/createorupdate) to create tags for azure resources as mentioned by 4c74356b41.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{parentResourcePath}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}?api-version=2019-08-01
```

For below example I create a tag for my azure sql datebase using [az rest cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest).

```
az login --service-principal --username "<clientid>" --password "<clientpassword>" --tenant "<tenantid>"

$subscriptionId ="<subscriptionId >"
$resourceGroupName="<resourceGroupName>"

$uri = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/levi-sql-server/databases/levi_sql_database?api-version=2019-06-01-preview"

$body = '{\"tags\": {\"name\":\"firstdatabasetag\"},\"location\":\"westcentralus\"}'

az rest --method put --uri $uri --body $body
```

After tested I found some resource api may not support the latest `api-version=2019-08-01`.  Above api to update the database tag only support `api-version=2019-06-01-preview` and earlier. But no need to wrong, you will get warning with the supported api versions if you used an unsupported version.

For other ways to make calls to azure api, you can refer to [this blog](https://medium.com/@mauridb/calling-azure-rest-api-via-curl-eb10a06127).

There are other methods like azure powershell command(as mentioned by Sajeetharan) and [az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-update) that allow you to use its update command to set the tags property.

Comment: Hi @MeghP Did you check out above reply. Did it work out. Please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: Hi @Levi Lu-MSFT In context of Virtual Machine.                                                                                               
subscriptionID - subscriptionID
resourceGroupName - resourceGroupName
resourceProviderNamespace - Microsoft.Compute
parentResourcePath -???
resourceType-virtualMachines
resourceName-MYVM. I am finding it difficult to find the parentResourcePath.Could you please help out

Comment: You can select your Virtural Machine -> go to Properties under Settings on the left pane, there you will find the uri of the resource id of your virtual machine which you can use directly in your api call. You can also find the resource id in the **url**  on the top of the web page.

Comment: So,To make it more generic ...If we have to tag a resource,We can find the resource id and add other pieces of resource tag api and proceed.  can we use the same payload/body for put operation ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it in two ways.

**[(i) Using Powershell Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags)** below to add a new tag or update a existed tag with new value.

```
Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @( @{ Name="tag_name"; Value="tag_value" }) -ResourceId <resource_id>
```

**(ii) Use C#**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources.Models;       

//MyResourceOperation implemented interface IResourcesOperations 
MyResourceOperation resourceOpertion = new MyResourceOperation();

//Get a resource belonging to a resource group
Resource myResource = resourceOpertion.Get("resourceGroupName", "resourceProviderNamespace", "parentResourcePath", "resourceType", "resourceName", "apiVersion");

//update the assigned tag with a new value
myResource.Tags.Add("tagName", "updatedValue");
```

Comment: what do you mean "I doubt there is an API to do the same"? How do you think the above is working. by magic?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/createorupdate ?????????????????

Comment: may be i have gone through wrong link that time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags got it

Comment: yeah, thats the one i refered earlier :) and your one is correct . upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to figure out how to update tags for a specific Azure resource for a few days, documentation was unclear and could not understand how to do this using solutions in this thread.

Figured it out eventually by running the powershell command to do the same operation(has better documentation with examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources) and captured the API call using fiddler to figure out the format being used.

Updating the thread with my solution so that it is useful for others.

REST API documentation in the below link. I reached out to Azure support for help and they did not get back in the last 1 week.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/updateatscope

Example to add/edit a tag for a Virtual machine. Basically need to use the PATCH operation. the PUT operations replaces all existing tags.

Patch [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/>subscriptionId](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%3EsubscriptionId)</resourceGroups/>resourcegrp</providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/>VM Name</providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default?api-version=2019-10-01

```
$Body = 

{ 
  "operation": "merge", 
  "properties": { 
    "tags": { 
      "testtag": "testvalue", 
      "testtag2": "", 
      "existingtag": "updatedtagvalue" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Note: the operation "merge" is important for merging or editing tags. "Delete" for deleting specific existing tags and "replace" for replacing existing tags with new ones.